# Add bookmark folder to chrome browser on Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser

Does any one know how to programmatically create bookmark folders in Chrome on Android?

I found the answer to create bookmark from this link

[Add bookmark to chrome browser on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433480/add-bookmark-to-chrome-browser-on-android)

But don't know how to create bookmark folders.

Comment: I'm actually interested in reading bookmarks _with_ the folder structure. There is nothing on it either. Any pointers appreciated.